# AutoMenu and Tokens

Tags: 6, routes, tokens

I am working in Drupal 6.22 and want to know if anybody knows of a way to get tokens working with the [AutoMenu](http://drupal.org/project/automenu) module?  Its become a bit of an issue from a usability perspective and want to have this working with my breadcrumbs (using [menu_breadcrumb](http://drupal.org/project/menu_breadcrumb)).

For instance I have the ability to create multiple galleries, which fall under `/media/galleries/[gallery-title-raw]`, and the breadcrumb reads accordingly as `Home > Media > Galleries > [gallery-title-raw]`. It would make sense then for individual photos (photo node) to fall under its parent gallery. So when a user navigates to the full node for the photo, the breadcrumb should read: `Home > Media > Galleries > [gallery-title-raw] > [photo-title-raw]` and a hidden menu item for the photo is automatically created.

Here's hoping that someone out there found a way to make this work :)

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Custom Breadcrumbs](http://drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs) module integrates nicely with tokens and allows for per content type breadcrumb trails.  If your photos are linked to your gallery via a nodereference or something else that already has a token, using Custom Breadcrumbs would work without any coding.  If you are using a gallery solution where the photo content type doesn't have a token for the gallery it is associated with, you will have to implement the [Token module's hooks](http://drupalcode.org/project/token.git/blob/755da683a011bc4bc35f11c9e6e188df2987f843:/token.api.php) to add that data as an available token for use in Custom Breadcrumbs.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks! I'll take a look at Custom breadcrumbs and see if it can do what menu_breadcrumb does, plus the little extra bit I require. Trying to looking through the code to see if I can perhaps submit a patch.